Fix a HDD that got bricked due to reboot during formatting
Someone gave me a 1TB Western Digital WD10SPZX HDD that got bricked due to a reboot during formatting. The formatting was being done using Windows File Explorer. Western Digital Dashboard no longer detects the disk.
I am now trying to fix it (using Fedora Linux). Fedora sees the HDD but reports a size of 0B (/dev/sdb):
$ lsblk
# NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
# sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
# ├─sda1   8:1    0   600M  0 part /boot/efi
# ├─sda2   8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
# └─sda3   8:3    0 929,9G  0 part /home
#                                  /
# sdb      8:16   0     0B  0 disk
# sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
# zram0  252:0    0   7,6G  0 disk [SWAP]

Same with dd:
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb status=progress
# dd: writing to '/dev/sdb': No space left on device
# 1+0 records in
# 0+0 records out
# 0 bytes copied, 0.000169542 s, 0.0 kB/s

fdisk cannot access the HDD:
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
# fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Invalid argument

I also tried other commands to get some clues, but without success:
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb
# mke2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
# mkfs.ext4: Device size reported to be zero.  Invalid partition specified, or
#   partition table wasn't reread after running fdisk, due to
#   a modified partition being busy and in use.  You may need to reboot
#   to re-read your partition table.

$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb
# tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
# tune2fs: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/sdb
# Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb
# 
# /dev/sdb:
# 
# ATA device, with non-removable media
# Standards:
#   Likely used: 5
# Configuration:
#   Logical     max current
#   cylinders   0   0
#   heads       0   0
#   sectors/track   0   0
#   --
#   Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
#   device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
#   device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
#   cache/buffer size  = unknown
# Capabilities:
#   IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
#   Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
#   R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 0   Current = ?
#   DMA: not supported
#   PIO: pio0 
# Logical Unit WWN Device Identifier: 50014ee65dc51dac
#   NAA     : 5
#   IEEE OUI    : 0014ee
#   Unique ID   : 65dc51dac
# Checksum: correct

Do you have any idea to fix the HDD? I do not need to restore the data. I am just trying to fix the disk.

What model of HDD is it? Noisy HDD detected with 0,00Kb says If it is visible to the computer but reports its total capacity as zero, it's how some disk models say "I'm failing my own internal self tests.". That referenced answer suggests the HDD manufacturer might have a specific diagnostic program which might help, or at least identify the reason for the capacity being reported as zero.

Thanks. It's a Western Digital WD10SPZX. Unfortunately, I didn't found any diagnostic program on WD's website.

On following the links from the WD Blue PC Mobile Hard Drive page, ended up at Download, Install, Test Drive and Update Firmware Using Western Digital Dashboard. That is a Windows only tool, but is shown as supporting WD Blue HDDs. I haven't attempted to use it myself.

Side note: it seems you assume the malfunction of the HDD was a consequence of the reboot, but it may have been the other way around.

@ChesterGillon Thanks! I just tried the WD Dashboard software without success. It doesn't detect the disk.

@KamilMaciorowski The reboot was triggered by the person who gave me the disk; the formatting has been running for a long time and he got impatient...

Can you try an "ATA Secure Erase" through hdparm?

@grawity_u1686 Thanks! I followed this tutorial and I got SG_IO: bad/missing sense data.
